# Vertically align two columns input fields one with labels and other without label

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am making an application form for invoices. Now I made five columns in one row. Each column has input fields. The fourth and fifth column have four input fields but fifth column fields have no labels. Now what I need is to align both four column and fifth column using bootstrap classes without any custom CSS. Because I need no labels in fifth columns. After spending hours I can't figure out how to align both columns.

**Html:**

```html
      <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-3>
                 <div class="form-group"> 
                  <label for="inputEmail">field</label> 
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" 
                     placeholder=""> </div>     
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-3>
               <!--i am using these four lines code in every col for input fields for sake clarity i wrote it only here.
                  <div class="form-group"> 
                  <label for="inputEmail">field</label> 
                  <input type="text" class="form-control"id="" 
                     placeholder="item desc"> </div>     
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-3>
                
               </div>
               <!---fourth col-!>
               <div class="col-sm-3>
               </div>
               <!--fifth col--!>
               <div class="col-sm-3>
               <!-I need to align this column with the above column remeber this coloumn field does not have labels thats why I am not able to align both columns(fourth and fifth)-!>
               </div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't know how you can make 5 columns in a row with `col-sm-3`. That will only make 4 columns in a row and the fifth column is pushed to a new row.

If your 4th and 5th column both have 4 inputs, but only 5th column inputs don't have labels. Why not combine the 4th and 5th column into one column and use rows for their inputs?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 offset-sm-1">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Field</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Field</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Field</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Field 1</label>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="input 1 without label" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Field 2</label>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="input 2 without label" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Field 2</label>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="input 3 without label" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Field 2</label>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="input 4 without label" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/91237/

Comment: 4th and 5th input fields should not come under 1st to 3rd columns.

Comment: What? I don't get what you meant. I copied Field label and input for every column just for simplicity. That's just a place holder for your input fields.

Comment: thats the exactly i was looking. i am gonna look through for learning purpose.one more question plz bear with me. i need to put a button  under the first row of field and that button should create first row of field.how should i do that?

Comment: one more is it possible ,for my this problem,to use the `<table></table>` element?. i read this somewhere.

Comment: @stackOverFlowGeek: you can use `<table>` for the structure for this problem, but you will lose the responsiveness on smaller screens where the columns will become their own rows.

Comment: No I didn't. Explain more, or create a new post with mock up.

Comment: bro i forgot to tell u something that at fifth column having no label. i need that label.

Comment: I don't understand. You said there is no label on the fifth column. But you need that label now?

Answer (score 1):

Use   `mt-2` to `form-group` where `label` is empty.

Learn here about bootstrap-4 spacing:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-2">
                 <div class="form-group"> 
                  <label for="inputEmail">field</label> 
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" 
                     placeholder=""> </div>     
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-2">
                  <div class="form-group"> 
                  <label for="inputEmail">field</label> 
                  <input type="text" class="form-control"id="" 
                     placeholder="item desc"> </div>     
               </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-2">
                 <div class="form-group"> 
                  <label for="inputEmail">field</label> 
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" 
                     placeholder=""> </div>     
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-2">
                  <div class="form-group  mt-2"> 
                  <label for="inputEmail "></label> 
                  <input type="text" class="form-control"id="" 
                     placeholder="item desc" > </div>     
               </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-2">
                 <div class="form-group"> 
                  <label for="inputEmail">field</label> 
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" 
                     placeholder=""> </div>     
               </div>

                
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: tnx for the answer your fifth and fourth col are not aligned if i put some more fields.

Comment: i mean 4th and 5th input fields should not come under 1st to 3rd  columns.

Comment: it only to example you can remove it .... really appricate if you mark as answer and up vote

Comment: your answer is not entirely helpful but tnx for the effort. i just upvot your answer

Comment: maybe you have to use `col-2` because `xs` size does not exist in bootstrap-4